# Delete product Final total didn't reduced using php ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am creating a ecommerce site for my final year project. I am ran into the problem with delete the product . if I delete product  product has been deleted from database success. but final total didn’t reduced what I tried so far I attached below along with screen shot image below.

[image]

Table

```
 <div class="container">
                <table class="table table-striped" id="mytable">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ProductID</th>
                        <th>Productname</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Qty</th>
                        <th>Amount</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div style='text-align: right; margin:10px'>
            <label><h3>Total amount: </h3></label>
            <span style="font-size: 40px; color: #ff0911" id='total-amount'></span>
        </div>
```

Display the Products

```
<script> 
getProducts();
function getProducts() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'all_cart.php',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data) {
            data.forEach(function(element) {
                var id = element.id;
                var product_name = element.product_name;
                var price = element.price;
                $('#mytable tbody').after
                (
                    '<tr> ' +
                    '<td>' + id + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + product_name + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + price + '</td>' +
                    "<input type='hidden' class='price' name='price' value='" + price + "'>" +
                    '<td>' + "<input type = 'text' class='qty' name='qty' value='1'/>" + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + "<input type = 'text' class='amount' id='amount' disabled/>" + '</td>' +

                    '<td>' +  " <Button type='button' class='btn btn-primary' onclick='deleteProduct(" + id + ")' >Delete</Button> " + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>');
            });
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

**delete product function**

```
function deleteProduct(id) {
    $(this).find('deleteProduct').click(function(event) {
        deleteProduct($(event.currentTarget).parent('tr'));
    });
    var total = 0;
    $('.amount').each(function(e){
        total -= Number($(this).val());
    });
    $('#total-amount').text(total);
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'remove.php',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data: {id: id},
                    success: function (data) {
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert(xhr.responseText);

                    }
                });
}
</script>
```

**remove.php**

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    include "db.php";
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("delete from cart where id=?");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id);
    $id = $_POST["id"];
    if ($stmt->execute())
        {
            echo 1;
        }
    else 
        {
                echo 0;
        }
        $stmt->close();
        }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is js-related more then php related. Since the remove.php files looks fine you may have a problem with AJAX.

```
function deleteProduct(id) {
$(this).find('deleteProduct').click(function(event) {
    deleteProduct($(event.currentTarget).parent('tr'));
});
```

This looks weird already since you're using jquery "find" on a non-class. Maybe u forgot a dot? Should be $(this).find(".deleteProduct").... and if u do so remember to actually add the class.

Beside this when you delete your product via ajax you are never refreshing the table, so the product-row will still be present. When you calculate your total you are fetching your current table elements:

```
 var total = 0;
$('.amount').each(function(e){
    total -= Number($(this).val());
});
```

this will lead to incorrect values if you don't delete the row u're pressing delete onto.

```
$('#total-amount').text(total);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'remove.php',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {id: id},
                success: function (data) {
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    alert(xhr.responseText);

                }
            });
```

You should add to the success callback function the part where you are calculating totals, but before that, you should delete the table row with something like $("....").remove();

**Edit with correct code:**
First of all bring the jquery delete button listener out of your delete function and make it like this:

```
<script>
     $('.mydeletebtn').click(function(event) {
    deleteProduct($(this).data("rowid"));
    });
    function deleteProduct(id) {
     .....
    }
```

Then modify the HTML output for the delete row changing it like this:

```
'<td>' +  " <Button type='button' class='mydeletebtn btn btn-primary' data-rowid="'+id+'" >Delete</Button> " + '</td>' +
```

since you don't really need the onclick when u're using jquery. I modified it so that your rowid is passed as javascript data-attribute.

After all of this you need to actually handle the row delete + total update like this:

```
    var $parentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'remove.php',
                    dataType: 'JSON',
                    data: {id: id},
                    success: function (data) {
                        $parentRow.delete();
                        updateTotals();
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert(xhr.responseText);

                    }
                });
```

Your final JS should be something like this:

```
<script>
function updateTotals(){
var total = 0;
    $('.amount').each(function(e){
        total -= Number($(this).val());
    });
$('#total-amount').text(total);
}
$('.mydeletebtn').click(function(event) {
        deleteProduct($(this).data("rowid"),$(this));
        });
function deleteProduct(rowid,$row) {
         var $parentRow = $(this).closest("tr");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'remove.php',
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        data: {id: rowid},
                        success: function (data) {
                            $parentRow.delete();
                            updateTotals();
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                            alert(xhr.responseText);

                        }
                    });
        }

</script
```

Comment: I edited my answer, didn't really test the code but it should point you in the right direction. The indent isn't fixed too but if you are using any IDE it should make the code more readable. Hope it helped